# Outlook 2010 adds extra padding for a button created with a table

Tags: html, email, outlook

I would like to send an email with a button that has an orange colour but my email already has a green background colour so I am getting a white space around the button. My code for table below:

```
<div style="background-color:#18A355">
<table align="center" bgcolor="#f79026" border="0" cellpadding="5" height="30" style="max-width: 600px; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;" width="150">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-spacing: 0px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-family:trebuchet ms">REGISTER NOW</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried with and without DIV.

[Extra space around the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC9t8.png)

Adding the code below!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="background-color:#18A355;">
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><a class="validating" href="https://www.horizoncurriculum.com" target="blank"><img alt="Horizon Curriculum Logo" src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/OTg5NTM0/original/149a4444699b492f83f1a5f8312cd6e9.png" style="width: 200px; height: 81px; border: 0px none; outline-width: medium; outline-style: none; text-decoration: none;" /></a></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="color:#FFFFFF">Dear {!lastname_fix},</span></span></span></span></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></span></span></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">The Horizon Energy Curriculum is a tool to empower educators and motivate students.<br />
With resources such as in-depth lesson plans, teachers guides, and an online textbook,<br />
Horizon provides a powerful set of resources to support science educators. </span></span></span></span></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">​</span></span></span><strong><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><a class="validating" href="https://www.horizoncurriculum.com/#sample" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none">Click here to get a FREE lesson plan sample</span></a></span></span></strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">.</span></span></span></span></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:trebuchet ms">✔&nbsp;Energy science online book</span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">✔&nbsp;Complete STEM lesson plans</span></span></span></span></span></div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">✔&nbsp;Forum</span></span></span></span></span></div>

<div><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></span></div>

<table align="center" bgcolor="#f79026" border="0" cellpadding="5" height="30" style="max-width: 600px; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;" width="150">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
   <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-spacing: 0px;"><a class="validating" href="https://www.horizoncurriculum.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=1" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-family:trebuchet ms">REGISTER NOW</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms">&nbsp;</span></span></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

After the first fix it helped but not I have some extra padding at the top.

[New padding issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSScy.png)

Comment: Do you mind pasting more code? Maybe your entire template?
A bit hard at the moment to get full context of the issue, especially if the bug is being caused by something else in your code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added the code. I am sorry for the coding mess but I am working in Aweber so there could be many extras. This button always works for me in all newsletters. It just doesn't work when I have the green background for the whole email.

Answer (score 0):

Odd issue and it could be something else but an easy fix is to wrap the button in a full width table and add the green background colour to the wrapper.
Worked fine after adding the wrapper in my tests

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#18A355" align="center">
      <table bgcolor="#f79026" border="0" cellpadding="5" height="30" style="max-width: 600px; border-spacing: 0px; border-width: medium; border-style: none;" width="150">
        <tbody>
          <tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-spacing: 0px;"><a class="validating" href="https://www.horizoncurriculum.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=1" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-family:trebuchet ms">REGISTER NOW</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It kind of worked but now I have some extra padding on the top of the table. I will add picture to the post.

Comment: I also tried by removing cellpadding="5" to cellpadding="0" and made the button by height and width only but still the same problem.